# Select2 Control Not Working inside html Table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I placed two select2 controls in a page. One outside a table and the other inside it. With the code following, only the one outside the table works fine but the one inside does not at all. (Nothing happens when the control is clicked).

**HTML**

```
<select id="drpBizPartner" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" ng-model="vm.salesInvoice.cardCode" ng-options="x.id as x.cardName for x in vm.businessPartners" name="CardCode" style="width: 100%;">
   <option value="0">Select Business Partner</option>
</select>   //Outside the table

<select id="drpItem" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" ng-model="lineItem.item" ng-options="item as item.itemCode for item in vm.items" name="ItemCode" style="width: 100%;">
   <option value="0">Select Item</option>
</select>    //Inside the html table
```

**Javascript**

```
        $(function () {
            $('#drpBizPartner').select2();
            $('#drpItem').select2();
        });
```

After searching the internet, I discovered what I thought was a fix to get the `select2` control to work. The script is as follows;

```
        $table.on('post-body.bs.table', function () {
            $('#drpItem').select2();
        });
```

But the above code clears the items on both `select2` controls (outer and inner). Please how can I get them both to work perfectly? Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 3):

```
<table>
  <tr> 
    <td> <div id="drpItem" ></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>.
```

//your js code will be

```
 $('#drpItem').select2();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thanx Ferrrmolina for suggetion , i improved its soon.it was my 1st post

Comment: No problem, have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for your response. But you obviously don't understand the question. I have the control already in a table tag. But the control appears disabled. It is not a html issue. It is a jQuery issue

Comment: Dhaval. Did you see my question at all? You are just repeating everything I did the first time. check my question and you will see my edited answer in there already.

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha maybe i don't understand you correctly, but i guess this work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/xfacmsd5/1/ if not, can you explain a little more your problem?.

Comment: @Ferrrmolina It's so strange that this works on fiddle but not on my application. The one with Select Business Partner works but the one with drpItems doesn't. I tried a replica of my code on fiddle and it works perfectly. I don't know what is wrong with my application. See edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xfacmsd5/3/